# Issue with RobotFramework Connect To Database Using Custom Params

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, automation, robotframework, pyodbc

Getting Below Error
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53)'

```
    *** Settings ***
Documentation     Simple example using DBLibrary.
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           DatabaseLibrary 
*** Variables ***
${DBHost_ConnectionString}  'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER="hostname";UID="uname";PWD="******";DATABASE="dbname"'   

*** Test Cases ***

Connect Database
    Connect To Database Using Custom Params    pyodbc    ${DBHost_ConnectionString}
```

I tried all the solutions over internet, like adding port to connection string, appending tcp before servername, e.t.c,
Followed the implementation mentioned in the source code of dbapi
https://github.com/franz-see/Robotframework-Database-Library/blob/master/src/DatabaseLibrary/connection_manager.py

```
 elif dbapiModuleName in ["pyodbc", "pypyodbc"]:
            dbPort = dbPort or 1433
            logger.info('Connecting using : %s.connect(DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%s,%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s)' % (dbapiModuleName, dbHost, dbPort, dbName, dbUsername, dbPassword))
            self._dbconnection = db_api_2.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%s,%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s' % (dbHost, dbPort, dbName, dbUsername, dbPassword))
```

Any help should be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As a guess, you shouldn't surround your connection string with single quotes, as they become part of the connection string. Robot is not python, and robot is not the shell, so you don't normally need to quote strings.

```
*** Variables ***
${DBHost_ConnectionString}  DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER="hostname";UID="uname";PWD="******";DATABASE="dbname"
```

It's not clear if you're literally using the string `hostname` and `uname`, etc., or if that's just boilerplate for the purpose of the question. You need to be passing the actual hostname and actual username and password.

You may not need the quotes around the other values, in which case it would look like this:

```
*** Variables ***
${DBHost_ConnectionString}  DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=hostname;UID=uname;PWD=******;DATABASE=dbname
```