# Getting OperationalError while connecting to SQL server with pyodbc in robot framework whereas the same works fine in usal python code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, robotframework, pyodbc

Below is my code for Robot framework which is `testcase.txt:`

```
*** Settings ***
Library           DatabaseLibrary
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
testcase1
    Connect To Database Using Custom Params    pyodbc    Trusted_Connection= 'no' , Driver = '{SQL Server}', Server = 'APAAUEVDF23/AVNDHDKAHS', Port='1433', Database = 'databasename', UID='AppUser' , PWD='password' , 
    ${group1Add}    Query    select top 5 *from table_name
    Disconnect From Database
```

The above test case is being called from the below batch file `runautomation.bat` passing the related python packages

```
C:\Python373\Scripts\pybot.bat --outputdir C:/Automation/Logs/%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2% --argumentfile C:\Automation\argfile.txt --listener C:\Python373\Lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\TestRunnerAgent.py:52797:False C:\Automation\Testautomation\testcase.txt
```

Upon running this script getting below error:

```
C:\>Automation\RunAutomation.bat

C:\>C:\Python373\Scripts\pybot.bat --outputdir C:/Automation/Logs/20230704 --argumentfile C:\Automation\argfile.txt --listener C:\Python373\Lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\TestRunnerAgent.py:52797:False C:\Automation\Testautomation\testcase.txt
unable to open socket to "localhost:52797" error: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
TestRunnerAgent: Running under CPython 3.7.3

===========================================================================================================
Testcase
===========================================================================================================
testcase1                                                                                     | FAIL |
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testcase                                                                                           | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
===========================================================================================================
Output:  C:\Automation\Logs\20230704\output.xml
Log:     C:\Automation\Logs\20230704\log.html
Report:  C:\BAutomation\Logs\20230704\report.html
```

PS: I've googled below solutions which didn't work:
-Tried putting tcp as `Server = 'tcp:APAAUEVDF23/AVNDHDKAHS'`
-Also `Trusted_Connection='no'` doesn't helps.

However my pyodbc connection works perfectly fine with python import from the same python directory like below:

```
C:\python373>python
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyodbc
>>> cn =  pyodbc.connect(    Trusted_Connection='no',    Driver='{SQL Server}',    Server='APAAUEVDF23/AVNDHDKAHS', Port='1433',    Database='databasename', UID='AppUser'  , PWD = 'password')
>>>
```

Also to verify that the dependent robot libraries are properly installed, I tried below script which runs perfectly fine to open a portal and sign-in to it:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           DatabaseLibrary
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
testcase1  
Open Browser    https://portal.xyz.com/AA/login.aspx    chrome
    Input Text    LoginName    appuser
    Input Password    Password    Test@123
    Sleep    2s
    Click Element    LoginBtn
    Sleep    10s
    [Teardown]    Close Browser
```

Can someone please help to resolve the above Error ?

Comment: Update: If I'm removing the single quotes from the connection string like this:
   Connect To Database Using Custom Params    pyodbc    Trusted_Connection= no, Driver = {SQL Server}, Server = 'PAAUEVDF23/AVNDHDKAHS, Port=1433, Database = databasename, UID=AppUser, PWD=password

then getting Syntax Error at Line no.1.  This hint was referred from below link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65686610/issue-with-robotframework-connect-to-database-using-custom-params